# Entity Framework. Как получить реальный тип сущностей для обоих сторон отношения во время сохранения сущности?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Мне нужно обработать процесс сохранения данных EF для того, чтобы сросить кэш приложения, кэш сбрасывается по имени сущности, для этого используется метод обработчик SavinChanges, который вызывается на контексте при изменении данных

Коллекция объектов `ObjectStateEntry`может содержать записи для сущностей и для изменения отношений между сущностями. Для сущностей все работает, как ожидалось, так как есть ссылка `Entity`

Для записей-отношений есть проблема. Если привести тип сэта к записи к `AssociationSet`, и проверить концы отношения, чтобы получить тип каждой сущности и потом по ее имени сбросить кэш, то возвращается неверное имя типа.

Оно выглядит так: `SomeSolution.DataAccess.SomeEntity`, то есть имя сборки и кратное имя сущности, а на самом деле сущность имеет имя `SomeSolution.DataAccess.Entities.SomeEntity`, то есть `ElementType.FullName` возвращает имя без полного namespace.

Может быть есть другой способ получить имена типов при обновлении связей?

```
    private void objectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cacheProvider != null)
        {
            var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
            var entries =
                objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added);

            if (entries != null && entries.Any())
            {          
                var entity = entries.Where(entry => !entry.IsRelationship).Select(r => r.Entity).FirstOrDefault();
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    var typeName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType())?.ToString();
                    _cacheProvider.ResetCache(typeName);
                }

                foreach (var entry in entries.Where(entry => entry.IsRelationship))
                {
                    var set = entry.EntitySet as AssociationSet;
                    if (set != null)
                    {
                        //Сеты для типов с первого и второго конца отношения
                        var firstEntitySet = set.AssociationSetEnds[0].EntitySet;
                        var secondEntitySet = set.AssociationSetEnds[1].EntitySet;

                        var firstEntityType = firstEntitySet.ElementType.FullName + "," + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
                        var secondEntityType = secondEntitySet.ElementType.FullName + "," + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

                        var firstTypeName = Type.GetType(firstEntityType).ToString();
                        var secondTypeName = Type.GetType(secondEntityType).ToString();

                        _cacheProvider.ResetCache(firstTypeName);
                        _cacheProvider.ResetCache(secondTypeName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `CorrespondingAssociationEndMember` можно получить тип, если навигационные свойства есть с обеих сторон отношения, если это не так, то, действительно, можно получить тип через `set`, используя имя пространства имен для CLR типа в схеме edm

```
                        var clrTypeNamespace = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation:ClrType";

                        var firstEdmType = set.AssociationSetEnds[0]?.EntitySet?.ElementType;
                        var secondEdmType = set.AssociationSetEnds[1]?.EntitySet?.ElementType;

                        var firstType = firstEdmType?.MetadataProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == clrTypeNamespace)?.Value as Type;
                        var secondType = secondEdmType?.MetadataProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == clrTypeNamespace)?.Value as Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получить информацию о навигационном свойстве в EF Code First:

```
var asem = set.AssociationSetEnds[0].CorrespondingAssociationEndMember;
var propInfo = asem.MetadataProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "ClrPropertyInfo")?.Value as PropertyInfo;
```

А оттуда уже можно получить и имя типа, и что угодно.

Попробуйте также посмотреть в отладчике коллекции `set.MetadataProperties`, `set.ElementType.MetadataProperties` и `().ElementType.MetadataProperties`- может быть, там будет более прямой способ получения информации о типе.

Comment: Этот способ подходит для случая, если с обоих сторон отношения есть навигационные свойства. В моем случае это не так, но тем не менее реальный тип можно получить следующим образом